# Personalizar player do Youtube em Iframe

Tags: youtube

Tenho uma parte do site que é gerenciável, ele recebe o `<iframe>` do **Youtube**, só que eu gostaria de poder personalizar esse player, tirar algumas coisas, como o tempo de duração, e outros botões que poluem o player.

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Vc já tem alguma coisa feita ou não tem ideia do que está fazendo?

Comment: @GustavoCinque tenho sim, mas é só um `<iframe>` normal do Youtube

Comment: Meu amigo, eu comentei a primeira vez, achando que vc não realizou nenhuma busca pela internet para vir a perguntar aqui, peço desculpas por isso. O que consegui encontrar e acredito que possa ajudar é o [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbT06COoDHI) em que o autor ensina a utilizar uma própria ferramenta do google. Espero que ajude. Sobre modificações de botões, não encontrei muita coisa.

Comment: Nas minhas pesquisas acabei encontrando o site [ReEmbed](https://app.reembed.com/users/signup?ref=topButton) onde você pode criar o seu próprio player.

Comment: isso foi muito útil cara, transforma em resposta para eu poder votar nela.

Comment: Vou fazer isso então.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe, após minhas pesquisas, encontrei algumas informações.

Esse [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbT06COoDHI) que explica como utilizar a ferramenta nativa do Google para modificações. O sistema de importação é extremamente fácil de usar e de aprendizado, já que é gerado na própria página da ferramenta o link de acesso ao video com as configurações escolhidas, além de cada campo ter sua explicação, cada um com seu hint, e valores possiveis. ([Link para a ferramenta](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=pt-br))

Há também uma ferramenta online [aqui](https://app.reembed.com/users/signup?ref=topButton), onde você pode escolher entre padrões pré definidos de layout para o seu vídeo, além de customizações quanto a cor e marca d'agua. Criando uma conta, é disponibilizado a opção de salvar o formato do player para futuras utilizações.

Answer (score 0):

Sim. Existe a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1) que se baseia nos parâmetros do player.

Com o autohide, você pode ocultar, por exemplo, a barra de progresso.
autoplay serve para ser  iniciado o vídeo automaticamente ou não.
As cores através do color, sendo válidos o vermelho e branco, padrão do YT.
Entre outros...